# How to use pyspark on yarn-cluster mode by code

Tags: apache-spark

This is my code.

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder. \
        master("yarn"). \
        config("hive.metastore.uris", settings.HIVE_URL). \
        config("spark.executor.memory", '5g'). \
        config("spark.driver.memory", '2g').\
        config('spark.submit.deployMode', 'cluster').\
        enableHiveSupport(). \
        appName(app_name). \
        getOrCreate()
```

I want to use this way to submit a task to a yarn-cluster.
But it throws an exception:

> Cluster deploy mode is not applicable to Spark shells.

What should I do?
I need use cluster mode, not client.

Comment: `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster`